# My Web application gives CORS error after adding HTTPS using Let's Encrypt

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, reverse-proxy, https, node.js

This is my application : https://cfslpro.com/student_portal/
Front end is done by AngularJS and back end is done by Node.JS. Hosted in Apache server. ( Digital ocean Linux 16.04 )

You can try login , username  : chanu & password is 123456.
Before adding SSL using Let's Encrypt, this application worked well.
Now i'm getting this error :

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://165.227.121.28:7000/api/user_manage/login. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

But you can run this URL without HTTPS on browser and it's working :

> http://165.227.121.28:7000/api/user_manage/login

Now I will show you some important sections in my Node.Js server code :

This is how I'm adding CORS plugin.

```
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

And this is how I create HTTP server :

```
app.listen(config.port, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
   } else {
        console.log("localhost:7000");
    }
});
```

i'm creating a HTTP normal server here.

And this is how i'm calling login end point from my front end.

> https://165.227.121.28:7000/api/user_manage/login

If I use this without HTTPS, i'm getting an error about `content blocked` because I can't call HTTP request from HTTPS environment. This is where I get CORS error.

This is my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/cfslpro.com.conf` file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        <Directory /var/www/cfslpro.com/public_html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

        </Directory>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName cfslpro.com
        ServerAlias www.cfslpro.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/cfslpro.com/public_html

        ProxyRequests on
        ProxyPass http://165.227.121.28:7000/api/user_manage/login https://localhost:7000/api/user_manage/login

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I think my reverse proxy configuration is wrong. I'm new to this proxy configuration and i followed some online examples. I followed this example too : http://www.codingtricks.biz/run-nodejs-application-apache/

This is my .htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Content-Type"
</IfModule>
```

Honestly I'm messed up now. Followed many guide lines and trying to fix this CORS error. Why this CORS giving us this much of errors and issues ?
Pleas help me guys. I'm someone who is trying to fix and learn. Please don't down vote this. 
I can even give server credentials to fix this issue. I spent whole week and now nothing to do. Please help me.

Comment: Please tell me if I need to remove or add anything. :(

Answer (score 0):

Use node **https** module and point/copy your certificate from Lets Encrypt cert directories of your live site

```
if (process.env.PROJ_ENV && process.env.PROJ_ENV == "PROD") {
  /**
   *  Execute SSL on Production
   */
  let sslOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("./ssl/key.pem"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("./ssl/cert.pem")
  };
  https.createServer(sslOptions, app).listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log(`Server running successfully on ${host}:${port}`);
  });
} else {
  app.listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log(`Server running successfully on ${host}:${port}`);
  });
}
```

Comment: I did generating some keys and added a https node sever. That didn't work too. To create virtual servers, i used this : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts    Do you think it's an issue ?

Comment: I did like this : 
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('server.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('server.cert', 'utf8');
var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};

Comment: app.use(cors({ optionsSuccessStatus: 200 }));

this is how I used cors module